# Remote MySql connection from other server

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I have to use MySql database which is lie on other server. I have it's IP, username and password.

How I can make connection with remote MySql data base. Is there need to give any permission to my IP address by remote MySql database provider. I think that would be mandatory

Give your opinions.

Thanks

Comment: My opinion is you haven't even tried to connect. You might try and report the approach and the error you get back

Comment: I have tried with this way but still errors related to mysql connectivity.SEE url : http://elbuso.softquanta.org/oslo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few steps to do, just follow [this tutorial](http://www.edwardbaker.net/2009/05/20/allow-access-to-remote-hosts-to-mysql/).

basically, you'll have to:

- enable networking
- set a bin-address
- grant access from another ip to your database-user

Answer (score 1):

To access Mysql database from another server, you have to enable mysql remote connection in the current server.So that you can access it. For more info just refer the following link  http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html