# Mysql connection from other computer to xampp server? Error 1045

Tags: mysql, xampp, connection, root

There is much information about this error but seems nothing works.

So I try to access to xampp mysql-server using the user root from local network.

mysql -uroot -p -h 192.168.100.48 --port=3306 (connecting from other local computer to xampp server)

But even I put right password (which I use for root) it not work. It works only if I log in using same computer where the server is running. I can use other user which I have specified but not root user. Why?

So how to fix this problem and getting it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the root user have the correct permissions?

Check the first duplicate link below for full answer - credit to Michael Berkowski:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.%'
    IDENTIFIED BY 'some_characters'  
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Have you tried search SO first? There are quite a few questions like this.

Possible duplicates:

[How to grant remote access permissions to mysql server for user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239131/how-to-grant-remote-access-permissions-to-mysql-server-for-user)

[Remote MySql connection from other server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382743/remote-mysql-connection-from-other-server)

Comment: Yes. My bad. Seems there was another topic for this but didnt find right words for it. I got this working using those details.

Comment: Glad to hear its working, if the answer helped you, could you accept it?

Comment: Yeah. But how to accept it? I m quite new using this.

Comment: Click the green check on the left of the answer ;)